# Failed Connec Elasticsearch port 9200 from server

Tags: elasticsearch, port

I have build a elasticsearch in my server. In server access success url: http://localhost:9200
But have a problem as: In client I have connect to my server and access http://10.252.6.82:9200 but not connect, not found http 404
(10.252.6.82) is IP my server

Who know solution for problem. please help me ! 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should edit network section in elasticsearch.yml to set "host" property to server's external IP. Also be sure that firewall settings on server are correct.
[Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html)

Comment: [Here are some more docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#common-network-settings) for network settings. By default, Elasticsearch only binds to loopback, so you will have to update the value of `network.host` to your external IP.